# Android VideoView synchronization of two videos

Tags: android, android-videoview

I am developing an Android application where two videos should be shown to the user simultaneously and they should be synced. I achieved this by using below algorithm:

```
int firstPercentage = (int)(100 * mVideoView1.getCurrentPosition() / (float)mVideoView1.getDuration());
int secondPercentage = (int)(100 * mVideoView2.getCurrentPosition() / (float)mVideoView2.getDuration());
if(mVideoView1.getBufferPercentage() < firstPercentage + 10 || 
    mVideoView2.getBufferPercentage() < secondPercentage + 10) {
        mVideoView1.pause();
        mVideoView2.pause();
}else{
        mVideoView1.start();
        mVideoView2.start();
}
```

Above algorithm basically guarantees that both two `VideoView` has at least 10 percent buffered video data to be played. However, I have a seekbar and play/pause button in my application. Hence above solution does not work because user can seek to a position that is not buffered yet. Anyone implemented such an app? Is there a good way to achieve this on Android?

Note: Videos are remote and their sizes are not small.